# Why howdoi module is not working on Pydroid3

Tags: android, python-3.x, pydroid

Im using Pydroid3 as editor and compiler. I want to get my doubts clear on the app itself. I have installed howdoi module on the terminal. But when asking a question it shows syntax error.

I tried
Import howdoi
howdoi list comprehension

And i got this
File "<string>", line 2

```
howdoi list comprehension

       ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]

Comment: Maybe checkout the authors documentation: http://gleitz.github.io/howdoi/howdoi_advanced_usage/

Also how do I does not teach humans how to do code, it shows how to write a code. There's a difference, in that perspective Here's an example: 

howdoi check if list is empty in python

Answer (score 0):

I tried ddgr on terminal and it is doing well.
According to issue 3770 there is something wrong with Android itself while going with howdoi.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).